# Can't get Jquery plugin to run slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying for awhile to get this plugin to run on my webpage but I can't figure it why it's not working...any help would be greatly appreciated! (I included all the files found in the plugin that I downloaded in the source folder).

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="\\ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script lang="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        });
    </script>
    <title>Stanley Cup Championships</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Stanely Cup Championships!</h1>
    <?php
    include 'header.php';
    ?>
    <p id="greeting">This is a website where you can find info about the team that won the stanely
        cup in any given year. The website is completely run by it's users, so sign up 
        and register your username and password in order to start inputting information 
        immediately! Have fun!</p>



    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="http://image.b4in.net/resources/2013/09/18/1379498716-Cup.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/First_Stanley_Cup.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://assets.dnainfo.com/generated/chicago_photo/2015/06/chicago-black-hawks-1938-1434298796.jpg/extralarge.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="https://i.embed.ly/1/display/resize?key=1e6a1a1efdb011df84894040444cdc60&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fmedia%2FBVGhOgWCUAADqif.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <?php
    include 'footer.php';
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Paul pls accept my answer!!!! hover beside the answer and a check mark will appear. click it (once)

Answer (score 0):

try this: adjust your javascript to

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  infiniteLoop: false,
  hideControlOnEnd: true
});
```

thats for manual

for auto use

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true
});
```